# How to use table listeners in corona sdk and how it works?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

can any one explain to me table listeners ? how to use it? when and why?
and explain to me the following code

```
local object = display.newImage( "ball.png" )
object.id = "ball object"

local function onObjectTouch( self, event )
    if event.phase == "began" then
        print( "Touch event began on: " .. self.id )
    end
    return true
end 

object.touch = onObjectTouch
object:addEventListener( "touch", object )
```

Comment: Its very clearly explained here https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/EventListener/addEventListener.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions can be stored in variables (both global and local) and in tables, can be passed as arguments, and can be returned by other
functions.

When we talk about a function name, such as print, we are actually talking about a variable that holds that function.

```
a = {p = print}
a.p("Hello World")
print = math.sin
a.p(print(1))
sin = a.p
sin(10, 20)
--> Hello World
-- ’print’ now refers to the sine function
--> 0.841470
-- ’sin’ now refers to the print function
--> 10      20
```

a function definition is in fact a statement (an assignment, more specifically) that creates a value of type “function” and assigns it to a variable.
we can store functions not only in global variables, but also in table fields and in local variables. Such definitions are particularly useful for packages: because Lua handles each chunk as a function, a chunk may declare local functions, which are visible only inside the chunk.

-------------------------- ***The differences*** ---------------------------

**Function Listener**

```
local object = display.newImage( "ball.png" )
object.id = "ball object"

local function onObjectTouch( event )
    if event.phase == "began" then
        print( "Touch event began on: " .. event.target.id )
    end
    return true
end
object:addEventListener( "touch", onObjectTouch )
```

in function listener you add an event listener to an object. when touch event is somehow dispatched, onObjectTouch **function** is going to be called.

**Table Listeners 1**

```
local object = display.newImage( "ball.png" )
object.id = "ball object"

local function onObjectTouch( self, event )
    if event.phase == "began" then
        print( "Touch event began on: " .. self.id )
    end
    return true
end 

object.touch = onObjectTouch
object:addEventListener( "touch", object )
```

in table listener 1, you have an object (to be more specific A TABLE). you add a key to your object as touch and supply this key by onObjectTouch value. so after you add touch event listener to your object, corona will search for the key value "touch" in object TABLE and this is why you enter your object as second entry, not the function(in this method corona wants the main table not the function): `object:addEventListener( "touch", object )`. 
In onObjectTouch method you have now two entries: self and event. self is your object and event is your touch event as usual.

**Table Listener 2**

```
local object = display.newImage( "ball.png" )
object.id = "ball object"

function object:touch( event )
    if event.phase == "began" then
        print( "Touch event began on: " .. self.id )
    end
    return true
end 
object:addEventListener( "touch", object )
```

in the third method please pay attention to the main difference: in case of using `object.touch = onObjectTouch` we use `object:onObjectTouch`. Remember whenever you use this structure it means:

```
object:onObjectTouch(...) ≣ onObjectTouch(self, ...)
```

therefor in this last approach we don't need to tell corona: hey corona object has a key called "touch" with value of "onObjectTouch": `object.touch = onObjectTouch`

Comment: thank you very much. that is really clear.but i want to ask: so why don't we always use function listeners and keep tables away??

Comment: It's up to your need. sometimes you just want to call a function doing a duty so you use for example function listeners, sometimes you want to call a function by an object and in that function change the object, so you use for example table listener 2. 
examples above are all for touch listeners, think of others: you want to update an object:object:update(). You just want to calculate a formula so you just call a function simply...
Hope this helps you. If this conversation solved your problem and confusion, please close this and vote up. THNKS

Answer (score 0):

Create Display Object

```
local object = display.newImage( "ball.png" )
object.id = "ball object"
```

Create the function that should get run when the appropriate event it raised.  In this case, a touch event.

```
local function onObjectTouch( self, event )
    if event.phase == "began" then
        print( "Touch event began on: " .. self.id )
    end
    return true
end
```

Assign a listener to the object that fires on a touch event.  You can also assign listeners for collision on a specific object.

```
object.touch = onObjectTouch
object:addEventListener( "touch", object )
```

This is a local listener assigned to a specific object.  Hence, that method will only fire if that specific object is touched.

This is great to turn display objects into buttons and detect collision between a single object and it's world.

There are other ways to handle this as well.  Instead of listening for a specific object to fire an event, you can create Runtime listeners.  These will listen for a specified event (Touch, collision, etc).  Any event of that type, regardless of the object will trigger the method.

In my opinion, I find it easier to create listeners for my objects rather than runtime listeners.  This way, I do not have to filter through what objects were involved in the event and then fire an appropriate method from there.

Summary: Listeners on objects fire only when that object is involved.  This lets you route directly to a method intended for that object when the event fires.  Runtime listeners fire any time the event occurs.  From there, you would have to figure out which objects were involved and what methods to route from.

Comment: Thanx for your explanation. I actually know the difference between local events and global. But I'm asking about the difference between this type of listener and the direct function listener, in orher words, why don't I write: object:addEventListener("touch",aNameOfFunction) instead of:  object:addEventListener("touch",object).          What are the differences and when should i use each type?